# asp.net quiz application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i want to create asp.net webforms, contain single multiple choice question on a form using formview
que. and ans. from sql server table(sqldatasource).
please give me a basic idea
thanks

Comment: What *basic idea* do you expect? Have you already started thinking about how do you intend to organize your database, etc...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple asp.net website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635054/simple-asp-net-website)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new website/web application in Visual Studio
2. Drag a FormView control from the Visual Studio toolbox to the Default.aspx page of your application.
3. Drag a SQL data-source from the toolbox to the same page, associate it with the FormView and the database.

You are up and running.

That was a very high-level idea of how to go about it. No one would be able to guide you step-by-step and make you learn all the aspects. You'd need to start fiddling with it on your own.

Following links would give you a head-start:

- [Build Your First ASP.NET Application with ASP.NET Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/build-your-first-asp-net-application-with-asp-net-web-forms)
- [Querying Data with the SqlDataSource Control](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/querying-data-with-the-sqldatasource-control-cs-)
- [Data Access Related Videos](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data)