# Quiz in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am making the Quiz Engine in Asp.Net MVC3. In my data base I have the collection of the question.

In each question I have a following column in my database

```
Question
Answer1
Answer2
Answer3    
Answer4
```

I quiz has 10 or 20 questions. On a page only one question will be display.

When user clicks on the next then first the result of the current question has
been saved in the database and then displays the next question.

I have confused who it would be implemented. Because I am getting 10 questions from the
database how I display it one by one and on every next button save the result of the current question in the database.

Please help me out from this problem. Please provide me some sample code.

Comment: take a look on http://forums.asp.net/t/1694191.aspx/1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645919/asp-net-quiz-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PagedList NuGet Package

Check out the demo on the page below.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application